# Creating and writing to a file with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, file, file-io

Here is my Java code.

```
File file = new File(path);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
//Do something.
out.println(sw.toString()); //Works fine; prints.
try {
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, sw.toString(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
```

I don't already have the file created, and neither is it creating it after the execution. 
How can I do this?

Comment: So... do you get an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `StringWriter`, use [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) instead:

```
 PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(file);
 w.print(string);
 w.flush();
 w.close()
```

Comment: This is possible, but the posted code is simpler and should work. Let's try to find out why it fails.

Comment: If you use this answer, specify the encoding in the Writer constructor. Otherwise the encoding used will be platform dependent. The only Writer I can see that let's you do this is OutputStreamWriter.

Answer (score 2):

See [`File.createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29).

> Atomically *creates a new, empty file* named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. ..

As mentioned by @JohnWatts in comments:

> ..both `PrintWriter` and your code create the file, but  pre-1.3 `FileUtils.writeStringToFile` does not.

Comment: If he is using Apache Commons `FileUtils` (with v >= 1.3), then he is [already having the file created if necessary, including parent dirs](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). So there is no need for `File.createNewFile()`.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
what if later i want to use the name of the file; what is the name of the file created int his case.? thanks

Comment: @Andrew Thompson i.e. where exactly am i specifying the path?

Comment: @Kraken If you are using FileUtils with a version greater than 1.3, then I think you can ignore this answer as your file should be created automatically for you. Please post the exception you are no doubt receiving so we know why the writing to file has failed.

Comment: @Kraken  What version of the `FileUtils` API are you using?  I am getting some down votes for suggesting a J2SE method that would seem to solve the stated problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm undoing my downvote. I think Duncan and I were trying to get more information from Kraken to make sure the answer we gave was actually appropriate. Given the answer he accepted, I now think you correctly anticipated his problem. It would have been nice to have an exception message.

Comment: I can't change my vote now. If you want to edit the answer to explain that both PrintWriter and your code create the file, but pre-1.3 writeStringToFile does not, I will upvote.

Comment: @John I used your words with one tweak.  Good call to ask for more details, the exception output etc..  It sure would have been useful.

Answer (score 1):

`I checked the code and it works.`

The only problem that I could think of is `path` value. Try with hardcoded path value. Because I doubt file is getting created and you are not able to find it.